# Why is npm start not working in react app?

Tags: reactjs

I tried to run npm start to a React app that it was working perfectly, but now for some reason is not working. The mesage I recive is the following:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\albat\Desktop\personal_projects\alba_virtual_cv\index.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:793:17)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:686:27)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1043:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! alba_virtual_cv@1.0.0 start: `node index.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the alba_virtual_cv@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\albat\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-05-11T09_08_43_976Z-debug.log
```

And my package.json is the following:

```
{
  "name": "alba_virtual_cv",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "debug": "^4.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "description": ""
}
```

Please I need help to run the application again.

Thank you.

Comment: did you use npx create-react-app app_name or something else ?

Answer (score 0):

Run this before starting the project:

`npm -i`

This installs missing packages

Comment: Hi thanks but I have the same error after using your solution.

Answer (score 0):

It just means something went wrong when dependencies were installed the first time.

I suggest doing these three steps:

1. `npm install -g npm@latest` to update npm because it is sometimes buggy.
2. `rm -rf node_modules` to remove the existing modules.
3. `npm install` to re-install the project dependencies.

This should fix the problem.

Comment: Hi thanks but I have the same error after using your solution.